# Manually created MacOS apps being deleted

Tags: macos, bundle, code-signing

I have some standalone apps that I manually created on my macOS. They keep getting deleted from the Applications folder from time to time, not sure how or why.

The source app I use to create them, in Documents folder also gets deleted. I have a backup of it all so that's good, but it's annoying to have to copy them back.

I manually created the .app bundle and added the necessary folders and files inside. The apps I created basically run a .sh file to automate some tasks.

They're not code signed or notarized, so I am suspecting it's macOS protection that must be deleting them. And even though I tried to code sign and notarize, it seems I need a developer id, which I don't want to acquire.

Does anyone know why are they being deleted and how to prevent that?

Comment: How are you creating them? What app are you creating them using?

Comment: I am guessing the core issue is that your computer sees the program that is creating these apps as a security threat.

Comment: I am not using any program. I am creating them manually. I create the .app folder, subfolders, info.plist, icns, etc... and that's it.

Comment: I've never heard of macOS automatically deleting unsigned apps from the Applications folder. macOS can be configured to refuse to run unsigned apps, but it doesn't delete them. I think something else is going on. Do you run any third party "system cleaner" / "disk cleaner" type apps?

Comment: Is this a work computer owned by your employer?

Comment: I'm not running any sort of "system cleaner" / "disk cleaner" apps. Once it happened right after I enabled and disable SIP. I rebooted and they were all gone. Now, it happened after installing Xcode and running some commands to change their attributes. The computer is owned by me only. I am trying a work around, I just put them all inside a folder in Applications and locked the folder with "chflags uchg". Let's see how long it lasts...

Comment: I am not very familiar with codesign or notarization, but I guess I was able to codesign them successfully. I first ran "xattr -cr" in all of them and then "codesign --force --deep --sign - ". First I was trying to inform a certificate and it wasn't working. I hope that helps too.